# why doesn't python return result using regex when there's more than one match?

Tags: python, regex

Here's the code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'ea') 
match = pattern.match('sea ea')
if match:
    print match.group()
```

the result is null. But when I change the code to `pattern = re.compile(r'sea')`, the output is "sea"

Could anyone give me an explanation?

**p.s.**
Btw, What I want is to retrieve the "#{year}" from string "select * from records where year = #{year}", plz give me an usable regex. Thanks in advance!

**Summary:**

Thanks to ALL of u, I find it in the document of python with your instruction. since I can select only one most appropriate answer, I just give it to the one who answered most quickly. Thx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern.match` is anchored at the beginning of the string.

You need `pattern.search`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

Answer (score 2):

You mean to use `search`, not `match`. `match` will match the regular expression only if it is at the *start* of the string.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'ea') 
match = pattern.search('sea ea')
if match:
    print match.group()
```

Answer (score 0):

`match` just matches, it doesn't search for things. This does:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(#{\w+})') 
>>> pattern.split('select * from records where year = #{year}')
['select * from records where year = ', '#{year}', '']
```